# infinite loop on non-numeric input in java

Tags: java

This is a simple java function taking an input in double. It takes an input and first check if the value is non-numeric. And then check if the value is greater than 0 or not.

The problem I am facing is every time I enter a non-numeric input, it runs an infinite loop and only print `"Enter a number greater or equal to 1.0: "`

```
double getInput(double n) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean check = false;
    while (!flag) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number greater or equal to 1.0: ");
        try {
            n = kbd.nextDouble();
            if (n >= 0 || n < 0)
                check = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            err.print("Invalid Data Type (not Numeric)");
        }
        if (check == true) {
            if (n < 0)
                System.out.println("Invalid value (too small)");
            else
                flag = true;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`kbd.nextDouble` does not consume new line characters, hence these will be repeatedly passed into the while loop.

In your catch block instead of just throwing an exception, you can pass kbd.nextLine() so that for the next loop your input method is ready.

```
catch(InputMismatchException ex)
            {

                System.out.println("Invalid Data Type (not Numeric)");
                kbd.nextLine();
            }
```

Here is the complete code for you:

```
double getInput(double n)
    {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean flag =false;
        boolean check = false;
        while(!flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number greater or equal to 1.0: ");
            try
            {

                n = kbd.nextDouble();

                if(n>=0 || n<0)check = true;
            }
            **catch(InputMismatchException ex)
            {

                System.out.println("Invalid Data Type (not Numeric)");
                kbd.nextLine();
            }**

           if(check==true)
           {
               if(n<0)
                System.out.println("Invalid value (too small)");
               else
                   flag = true;
           }
        }
    return n;
    }
```

Comment: i want to take input until the correct value entered

Comment: So even when you enter correct input the next time, your code isnt working?

Comment: I will add the new code with the reason why this is happening in a minute

Comment: See the answer and let me know if you didn't understand any part of it

Comment: its working fine...thanks a lot,,,
i understand the solution

Comment: If the solution works for you, dont forget to mark this as answer cheers

Answer (score 0):

Reading a double value from the scanner wont read the end of line

```
n = kbd.nextDouble();
```

so the scanner object will have something to read unless you get the line ending calling

```
kbd.nextLine();
```

the logic point to do this exactly after the exception comes...

```
 catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.err.print("Invalid Data Type (not Numeric)");
        kbd.nextLine();  ///here!!!
        }
```